# History tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been working now on a project for a period of time. The project has been released and is in production mode.

We have now noticed that one of the tables that stores events for products is growing rapidly, it produces around 6.5 million rows each month give/take a few 100 000. This makes of course the database to take up much hdd-space and it will not get smaller, around 12GB in size, we are on our way to getting out of space.

The thought of running a script each night to keep a low number of history rows has occurred to me, but this will of course not free up hdd-space, here I need to shrink the database file.  Have read around on the net about shrink of datafile.

And get pro and cons to why one should not do it. Could the handling of the history table be done in some other way, or should I run the delete script in a maintenance plan and once a week/month run a shrink job in a maintenance plan?

At moment I have a maintenance plan with: 
- Reorganize index (3 times a week)
- Update statics   (3 times a week)
- Clears old not needed rows in some tables. (every night)

The system it self has over 14 000 units making selects/writes each minute or 2 minute, it can sometimes be very slow and some sql-questions seems to get a command timeout (30s).

Comment: Which SQL server are you using?

Comment: We are using Sql Server 2008 R2 (ver 10.50.4000) to be exact and it is the standard edition (if I remeber it correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data archival can be tricky. You could copy the history to another database (perhaps on another server), which would help with your HDD space concerns. But even without talking about what you decide to do with the old data, once you delete it from your table, you shouldn't have to shrink your database. That space will be freed up inside of the database file, and you can reuse it for the incoming records in that table. The main reason you don't want to shrink is because you'll eventually grow out that file again when it needs the space, which will cause fragmentation and performance issues. Plus, you'll have a bunch of unnecessary IO for shrinking and growing the file, reorganizing/rebuilding those fragmented indexes, etc.

So I would say to leave the database file as it is and try to maintain it at the same size, just deleting and adding records to that big table. If it continues to grow because you keep adding more than you delete, then you'll need to figure out another solution, such as adding additional HDDs for more data files.

Comment: That seems like a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

You also have option to do table partitioning. You could have several filegroups assign to different disks and allocate these resources to the table. SQL will do horizontal table partitioning based on values you specified.

This is good overview for SQL table partitioning:
http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/partitioning.htm

If your table also actively inserted and deleted data - you will get better performance on truncate instead of delete. The only different is truncate operation is not logged, so you can't rollback the statement.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Keep the DB file size at the steady-state size of the data. Don't get into shrink-grow cycles. That's all. The shrink should be a one-time cleanup for you.

If deleting rows does not give you space back, shrink won't either. You'd need a reorganize or rebuild.